# How can I determine when Bloomd will scale the bloom filter?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, bloom-filter

I'm using Bloomd and its scalable bloom filter to store/check billions of urls for our broad crawler. It was working very good for first 1-1.5 billion urls and it has been using around 16 GB of memory but it seems that more than 2 billion urls will be added to it soon and I would like to understand when Bloomd will try to scale filter to 32 GB (and we will upgrade our server memory to 64 GB or more).

The "info" command provides some data but I'm not sure which key represents what and how can I understand how many url's I can add to it before it scales up.

Here is my "info" command results

```
START
capacity 5461000000
checks 5893888032
check_hits 5400239954
check_misses 493648078
in_memory 1
page_ins 7
page_outs 6
probability 0.000100
sets 493648075
set_hits 493648016
set_misses 59
size 1859303638
storage 17205844037
END
```

Also I'll appreciate if someone knows better approach than using Scalable Bloom Filters for that kind of massive URL sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is using only 34% of its capacity (size/capacity = 1859303638/5461000000).